# Searching within a ruby array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array filled with 0's, 1's, 3's and 4's and want to check inside the array, so that once a certain amount of the 4's have been found, a statement turns false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `count` method.

```
alist.count(4) >= n
# => true or false
```

`n` would be the certain number you want to check for.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is the best place to start answering questions like this, ruby has a very rich set of functions on [Array](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html#method-i-count) and [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerable.html)

```
def enough_4s?(array, how_many)
  array.count(4) >= how_many 
end

array = [1,1,1,2,3,4,4,4]
enough_4s?(array, 3)
#=> true
enough_4s?(array, 4)
#=> false
```

Comment: since `.count(4) > x` is shorter I don't see the need for an extra function

Comment: because it documents intention

Answer (score 0):

`[0,1,3,4,3].­count(4) > 2 => false`

(e.g 2 is the expected count)

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to immediately *stop* searching upon locating enough 4s, use `each` or `find` or equivalent, and `return` or `break`, rather than `count`. For instance:

```
n = 2
([0,1,3,4]*5).find do |i|
  n -= 1 if i == 4
  break false if n == 0
end
# false
```

Comment: `return` is no good here (`LocalJumpError: unexpected return`)

Comment: @UriAgassi: The example I wrote is not using `return`. It's using `break`. One with `each` could do the same. One with `map` would be similar too (don't forget to return `i` in that case, else you'll get an array of `nil`.)

Comment: You say in your explanation "... and `return` or `break`" - `return` won't work...

Comment: @UriAgassi: well, yeah, it won't work outside of a function. But I would assume OP isn't using IRB. `def foo; n = 2; ([0,1,3,4]*5).each { |i| n -= 1 if i == 4; return false if n == 0 }; end; foo`

Comment: You did not enclose it in a functions, so not using IRB may cause more confusion, as the whole function this snippet _will_ appear in will return unexpectedly.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, which stops as soon as it can is based on using `any?`:

```
def has_at_least?(arr, val, min)
  arr.any? do |i|
    i == val && (min -= 1).zero?
  end
end

has_at_least?([0,1,3,4]*5, 4, 2)
# => true

has_at_least?([0,1,3,4]*5, 4, 7)
# => false
```